# How can i remove item from jquery ui autocomplete rendered list

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to remove `item` from `jquery-ui autocomplete` rendered list

let say the item is **compton**

**Question**: i want to remove `item` "compton" once it is rendered from outside **NOT from** helper functions like `select,create,open` etc

**Below is my code:**

```js
 $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "john",
        "khair",
        "compton",
        "Jordan",
        "Micheal",
        "Peter"
    ];
    
   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
   }).focus(function () {
         $("#tags").autocomplete("search");
    });
   
   // logic to remove item "compton" must reflect in rendered ui
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Search: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: what is `NOT from helper functions like select,create,open`

Comment: just filter your tags `availableTags.filter(tag => tag!='compton')`

Comment: without giving source can't i directly remove from ui? if any way is there please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try using `option` [method](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-option) which sets one or more options for the autocomplete.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "john",
    "khair",
    "compton",
    "Jordan",
    "Micheal",
    "Peter"
  ];

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  }).focus(function() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete("search");
  });

  $("#tags").autocomplete("option", "source", availableTags.filter(i => i !== "compton"));
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: without giving `source` can't i directly remove from `ui`?  if any way is there please help me

Comment: you can get source using `$( "#tags" ).autocomplete( "option", "source" );` from anywhere.